# Show a list of users using Symfony

Tags: symfony, fosuserbundle

I'm trying to show the list of my users. I'm using FOSUser. This is my Controller in which I want to find the list of users in the fos_user table and show it in my affiche page:

```
<?php

namespace User\UserBundle\Controller;
use Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Controller\Controller;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request;
use User\UserBundle\Entity\User;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\RedirectResponse;
use User\UserBundle\Form\UserType;

use FOS\UserBundle\Controller\RegistrationController as BaseController;

class DefaultController extends BaseController
{
    public function indexAction()
    {
        $response = parent::registerAction();
        // ... do custom stuff
        return $response;
    }

    public function getDoctrine()
    {
        return $this->container->get('doctrine');
    }
         
    public function afficheAction()
    {   
        $em = $this->getDoctrine();
        $admins = $em->getRepository('UserUserBundle:User')->findAll(); 
        return $this->render('UserUserBundle:Default:affiche.html.twig', array('admins'=>$admins)); 
    }
}
```

But I get this error

> Call to undefined method User\UserBundle\Controller\DefaultController::render() in C:\wamp\www\pfe2\src\User\UserBundle\Controller\DefaultController.php

How could I resolve it?

Comment: does your config.yml is correct?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You probably use FOSUserBundle 1.3.x whose controller classes do not extend the base `Controller` class from the FrameworkBundle. Thus, you cannot use the shortcut methods provided by that class, but you have to render the template manually like it is done in the base `RegistrationController` class:

```
public function afficheAction()
{   
    $em = $this->getDoctrine();
    $admins = $em->getRepository('UserUserBundle:User')->findAll(); 

    return $this->container->get('templating')->renderResponse('UserUserBundle:Default:affiche.html.twig', array('admins'=>$admins)); 
}
```